# When I update my react app packages, it does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My `node.js` version is `16.13.1`.

I'am using these packages

```
"react": "^16.8.2",
"react-dom": "^16.8.2",    
"webpack": "^5.66.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "^4.7.3",
"webpack-manifest-plugin": "^4.1.1"
"babel-core": "6.26.3",
"babel-eslint": "7.2.3",
"babel-jest": "27.4.6",
"babel-loader": "8.2.3",
"babel-preset-react-app": "^10.0.1",
"babel-runtime": "6.26.0"
```

I'am trying to update my react app. but when I try to run my react app with `npm start`, I took this error.

> ValidationError: Invalid options object. Ignore Plugin has been
> initialized using an options object that does not match the API
> schema.
>
> - options should be one of these:    object { resourceRegExp, contextRegExp? } | object { checkResource }    Details:
>
>   - options misses the property 'resourceRegExp'. Should be:
>     RegExp
>     -> A RegExp to test the request against.
>   - options misses the property 'checkResource'. Should be:
>     function
>     -> A filter function for resource and context.

```
errors: [
    {
      keyword: 'anyOf',
      dataPath: '',
      schemaPath: '#/anyOf',
      params: {},
      message: 'should match some schema in anyOf',
      schema: [
        {
          type: 'object',
          additionalProperties: false,
          properties: { contextRegExp: [Object], resourceRegExp: [Object] },
          required: [ 'resourceRegExp' ]
        },
        {
          type: 'object',
          additionalProperties: false,
          properties: { checkResource: [Object] },
          required: [ 'checkResource' ]
        }
      ],
      parentSchema: {
        title: 'IgnorePluginOptions',
        anyOf: [
          {
            type: 'object',
            additionalProperties: false,
            properties: [Object],
            required: [Array]
          },
          {
            type: 'object',
            additionalProperties: false,
            properties: [Object],
            required: [Array]
          }
        ]
      },
      data: /^\.\/locale$/,
      children: [
        {
          keyword: 'required',
          dataPath: '',
          schemaPath: '#/anyOf/0/required',
          params: { missingProperty: 'resourceRegExp' },
          message: "should have required property 'resourceRegExp'",
          schema: { contextRegExp: [Object], resourceRegExp: [Object] },
          parentSchema: {
            type: 'object',
            additionalProperties: false,
            properties: [Object],
            required: [Array]
          },
          data: /^\.\/locale$/,
          children: undefined
        },
        {
          keyword: 'required',
          dataPath: '',
          schemaPath: '#/anyOf/1/required',
          params: { missingProperty: 'checkResource' },
          message: "should have required property 'checkResource'",
          schema: { checkResource: [Object] },
          parentSchema: {
            type: 'object',
            additionalProperties: false,
            properties: [Object],
            required: [Array]
          },
          data: /^\.\/locale$/,
          children: undefined
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  schema: {
    title: 'IgnorePluginOptions',
    anyOf: [
      {
        type: 'object',
        additionalProperties: false,
        properties: {
          contextRegExp: {
            description: 'A RegExp to test the context (directory) against.',
            instanceof: 'RegExp',
            tsType: 'RegExp'
          },
          resourceRegExp: {
            description: 'A RegExp to test the request against.',
            instanceof: 'RegExp',
            tsType: 'RegExp'
          }
        },
        required: [ 'resourceRegExp' ]
      },
      {
        type: 'object',
        additionalProperties: false,
        properties: {
          checkResource: {
            description: 'A filter function for resource and context.',
            instanceof: 'Function',
            tsType: '((resource: string, context: string) => boolean)'
          }
        },
        required: [ 'checkResource' ]
      }
    ]
  },
  headerName: 'Ignore Plugin',
  baseDataPath: 'options',
  postFormatter: null
}
```

Comment: The [IgnorePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/ignore-plugin/) seems to have been updated with [breaking changes](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/pull/14211/commits/80689230632ae58fdbca81366732736811c8d338). Check your `webpack.config.js` and review the implementation of the `IgnorePlugin`.

Comment: @kca thanks your answer. I tried that you said, But it still not works. Maybe, I could not do it. :)